# Data retrieved from firebase not showing up in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am fairly new in android studio. So when I click on the floating action button, put in new data, it stores the data in my firebase database but displays blank screen and a notification that "budget item added successfully" and the app does not crash either. I'm not sure what I did wrong in the code or maybe the codes were not properly typed. Any help would be appreciated very much.

Activity class.

```
public class TodaySpendingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView totalAmountSpentOn;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private ProgressDialog loader;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String onlineUserId = "";
    private DatabaseReference expensesRef;
    private TodayItemAdapter todayItemAdapter;
    private List<Data> myDataList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_spending);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar((androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar)toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Today's Spending");
        totalAmountSpentOn = findViewById(R.id.totalAmountSpentOn);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        loader = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        onlineUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        expensesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("expenses").child(onlineUserId);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        myDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        todayItemAdapter = new TodayItemAdapter( TodaySpendingActivity.this, myDataList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(todayItemAdapter);

        readItems();

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addItemSpentOn();
            }

            private void addItemSpentOn() {
                AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TodaySpendingActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(TodaySpendingActivity.this);
                View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_layout, null);
                myDialog.setView(myView);

                final AlertDialog dialog = myDialog.create();
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                final Spinner itemSpinner = myView.findViewById(R.id.itemspinner);
                final EditText amount = myView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
                final EditText note = myView.findViewById(R.id.note);
                final Button cancel = myView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                final Button save = myView.findViewById(R.id.save);

                note.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                save.setOnClickListener(view -> {

                    String Amount = amount.getText().toString();
                    String Item = itemSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String notes = note.getText().toString();

                    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Amount)){
                        amount.setError("Please input an amount!");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (Item.equals("Select item")){
                        Toast.makeText(TodaySpendingActivity.this,"Select a valid item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(notes)){
                        note.setError("Note is Requires");
                        return;
                    }

                    else {
                        loader.setMessage("Adding a budget item");
                        loader.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        loader.show();

                        String id = expensesRef.push().getKey();
                        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        String date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

                        MutableDateTime epoch = new MutableDateTime();
                        epoch.setDate(0);
                        DateTime now = new DateTime();
                        Months months = Months.monthsBetween(epoch, now);

                        Data data = new Data(Item, date, id, notes, Integer.parseInt(Amount), months.getMonths());
                        expensesRef.child(id).setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(TodaySpendingActivity.this, "Budget item added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(TodaySpendingActivity.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                                loader.dismiss();
                            }

                        });
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                });

                cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void readItems() {
        Query query = expensesRef.orderByChild("month").equalTo(new DateTime().getMonthOfYear());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                myDataList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Data data = ds.getValue(Data.class);
                    myDataList.add(data);
                }
                todayItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                int totalAmount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < myDataList.size(); i++){
                    totalAmount += myDataList.get(i).getAmount();
                    String stTotal = String.valueOf(totalAmount);
                    totalAmountSpentOn.setText(stTotal);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Adapter Class.

```
public class TodayItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TodayItemAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Data> myDataList;
    private String post_key= "";
    private String item= "";
    private String note="";
    private int amount = 0;
    public TodayItemAdapter(Context mContext, List<Data> myDataList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.myDataList = myDataList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.retrieve_layout, parent, false);
        return new TodayItemAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Data data = myDataList.get(position);

        holder.item.setText("Item: "+ data.getItem());
        holder.amount.setText("Amount: "+ data.getAmount());
        holder.date.setText("On: "+ data.getDate());
        holder.note.setText("Note: "+ data.getNotes());

        switch (data.getItem()){
            case "Transport":
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_transport);
                break;
            case "Food":
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_food);
                break;
            case "House":
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_house);
                break;
            case "Entertainment":
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_entertainment);
                break;
            case "Education":
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_education);
                break;
            case "Charity":
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_charity);
                break;
            case "Clothing":
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clothing);
                break;
            case "Health":
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_health);
                break;
            case "Personal":
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_personal);
                break;
            case "Other":
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_other);
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return myDataList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView item, amount, date, note;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            amount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            note = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check `addValueEventListener` is called when new data is stored

if yes then change code as mentioned below and try again

in readItems method

From

```
todayItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To

```
todayItemAdapter.addData(myDataList);
```

add method in `TodayItemAdapter` class as mentioned below

```
public void addData(List< Data> list){
    myDataList.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I followed your instruction but the data does not show up in the recyclerview still and the code seemed to be running fine.

Comment: okay then make sure recyclerview is showing properly in layout file (recyclerview is visible and full height width) and if it is okay then check layout file is properly visible (cell is visible and height width is not 0)